# Como converter uma string separada em vírgula e letra "e" no final para um array a partir dos números existes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como poderia extrair de uma string assim:

```
var texto = '4°, 5° e 6° ano';
```

Um resultado assim:

```
var array = [
   4,
   5,
   6 
];
```

Ou ainda melhor desta maneira:

```
var array = [
   '4° ano',
   '5° ano',
   '6° ano'
];
```

Eu tentei fazendo isso, mas não deu muito certo:

```
 $scope.filterRecomendations = function(recomend) {
   var list = recomend.split(' e ');
   var collection = [];
   for(var i in list) {
      list[i].split(', ')
      collection.push(list[i]);
   }
    collection.flat(Infinity); 
    return collection;
 };
```

Imprimiu uma coisa esquisita tipo isso no ng-repeat:

```
[["4º"]["5º"]["6º ano"]]
```

Exemplo quando tem apenas uma turma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que encontrei uma solução:

```
$scope.filterRecomendations = function(recomend) {
    var list = recomend.match(/\d+/g); 
        list.sort(function(x,y){        
                    return x - y;
        });
        var collection = [];
        for (var i in list) {
            collection.push(list[i]+'° ano');
        }
    return collection;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Vocè está ignorando o resultado do segundo `split` e acaba jogando o próprio `list[i]` nos resultados. O mesmo acontece com `flat`, que retorna outro array, mas você simplesmente ignora o retorno.

Uma forma de fazer seria retirar o "ano" do final, depois fazer o `split` por "e" ou vírgula, e depois adicionar "ano" em todos:

```js
let recomend = '4°, 5° e 6° ano';
let collection = [];
if (recomend.endsWith(' ano')) { // se termina com " ano"
    collection = recomend
        // retira o " ano"
        .slice(0, -4)
        // separa por vírgula ou "e", com espaços opcionais antes e depois
        .split(/\s*[e,]\s*/)
        // adiciona " ano" no final de todos
        .map(e => `${e} ano`);
}
console.log(collection); // [ '4° ano', '5° ano', '6° ano' ]
```

Ou, no seu caso:

```
$scope.filterRecomendations = function(recomend) {
    let collection = [];
    if (recomend.endsWith(' ano')) { // se termina com " ano"
        collection = recomend
            // retira o " ano"
            .slice(0, -4)
            // separa por vírgula ou "e", com espaços opcionais antes e depois
            .split(/\s*[e,]\s*/)
            // adiciona " ano" no final de todos
            .map(e => `${e} ano`);
    } // não sei o que deve fazer se não termina com " ano", então deixei assim mesmo
    return collection;
};
```